# Is Flex supporting *.rm files?

Tags: apache-flex, rm

So all is mentionned in the question : Can i run real player files with Flex ?

thanks.

Comment: Nope.  You can not play real player files with Flex.

Comment: @mistabell Why not?  He'd just be stuck writing his own ActionScript codec for rm files.  People have done it for alternate audio formats, such as ogg, why not for video?  That said, I perceive the process would be difficult at best and the results would not be very performance friendly.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com RealMedia are closed source proprietary formats/codecs

Comment: @mistabell Aren't most video codec/formats proprietary? ( Aside from Ogg Theora and WebM ).  That would certainly make a difficult project even more difficult; but it is hardly impossible.  I'd recommen tat the Original Poster look into converting the video instead of trying to play it in it's current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, it depends on the formats that your Media Server and your Flash Player supports